# Linux line oriented text file manipulation

Tags: linux, shell, command, text-files

I have a large text file (1,2,3 GB) organized as a sequence of lines, as follows:

```
   __________________________
   __________________________
   __________________________
             ...
   __________________________
```

What is the simplest way (command, bash script) to copy a portion of this file into a new file(e.g: copy everything from line 10 to line 1000) ? The line interval should be passed as a parameter.

Comment: I would suggest to learn to use `split` or `csplit` commands.

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -n 10,1000p input.txt > output.txt
```